# Add condition for row value (angular material)

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material, mat-table

I want to add a condition on the value of the current column. I can't read the value of curent row.
i don't know what the variable i must be used for check the condition i used row but is not defined

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="idCve">
    <th mat-header-cell matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> IDCVE </th>
    <ng-container ngIf="row.idCve != null; else dothis" >
        <td mat-cell matCellDef="let row"> {{row.idCve}} </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-template #dothid>
        <td mat-cell matCellDef="let row"> --------- </td>
    </ng-template>
</ng-container>
```

---

TS File

```
Constructor(vulnerabilityServiceService: VulnerabilityServiceService) {
    const vulnerabilities = vulnerabilityServiceService.getVulnerabilities();
    // Assign the data to the data source for the table to render
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(vulnerabilities);
}
```

Comment: where does vulnerabilityServiceService.getVulnerabilities() get the vulnerabilities from?

Comment: Hi achraf, have you look that the template have a wrong letter ID? `<ng-template #dothid>`, is this an example or the real code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe like this? :)

HTML

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
<ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <div *ngIf="element != 0; else elseDiv">
            {{element}}
        </div>
        <ng-template #elseDiv>
            ----------------
        </ng-template>
    </td>
</ng-container>
<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
```

TS

```
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position'];
  dataSource = [1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0];
```